# How to Create Wordpress Multisite user with network admin privleges

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I created a new user with Admin privileges and realized it cannot see the Network Admin menu.
I have one user with Network Admin, but I want to create a different user with those privileges.

Can't figure out how.

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For adding a user to the sites in Multisite first loge in with admin privilege that you have then go into the network setting and in the sites section on each sites you have to go in the users tab and then add the user you want to have the privilege or create one in there and the user will have the appropriate privilege